# how do I change the white space between my header and my div after my first header?

Tags: html, css

Somehow there is this fixed white space between the name "Larry Rosenburg" and the picture below it. No matter how I change the margin, it doesn't affect the distance. Here is a screen shot [screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I51u.png)

How can i shorten the white space?

here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Larry Rosenburg Official Website </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Crimson+Text:400,700,700i|Rakkas" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cherry+Swash|Cinzel|Gentium+Basic|Muli" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src ="lincoln.jpg" width ="27%" alt="Lincoln logo" id="logo_picture">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="http://www.lincolnlandservices.com/index.html"> Lincoln </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="clearfix">  </div>

        <div id="title"> 
            <p>Larry Rosenburg </p>
        </div> 

        <div id="profile">
            <img src="picture.jpg" width="25%" alt="" id="profile-pic" >
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>

</html>
```

And here is the css:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
}
#logo_picture{
    margin-left: 80px;
}

#logo img, #logo nav{
    float: left;
}
#logo nav{
    line-height: 120px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;

}

nav li{
    display: inline;
}

nav a{
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:'Arsenal', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 2px 38px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav a, nav a:visited {
    color: black;
}

nav a.selected, nav a:hover{
    color: grey;
}

#title{
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Anton','sans-serif';

}
#profile-pic{
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: url('picture.jpg');
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 0;

}



.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It would help quite a bit if you provided a working demo with the actual images you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS `margin: 30px auto;` of `#profile-pic` sets the top and bottom margin as 30px. That is the white space you are seeing. Either set the margin individually or set it all at once. Don't use the current style.

Before posting questions like this, please try to inspect the html element using any Web Browser. All web browsers shows the layout and margins of elements. It would help you in solving issues faster.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by setting the margin individually or all at once? I still don't know why this style is wrong. I did use chrome dev tool to check but it shows that the space doesn't belong to anywhere.

Comment: @Catherine When you are setting margin as `margin: 30px auto`, you are actually setting margin as `margin-top: 30px; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: auto;`. So either set it individually as `margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 10px;` or all at once as `margin: 30px 10px 30px 10px;`

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this. now you may try this because it works fine in my device.

```
 #profile-pic {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("picture.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-top: 0 none;
    display: block;
    margin: -60px auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[[here the screenshot][checked]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqzyU.png)

Comment: hey there! I tried this, but it only moved the pic to the left. The white space is still there.

Comment: oh dear give me some time i am checking this .;)

Comment: #profile-pic {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("picture.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-top: 0 none;
    display: block;
    margin: -60px auto;
    padding: 0;
}

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<p style="margin-bottom:0px">Larry Rosenburg </p>
```

There might be some margin-top on the image as well.

Comment: You should use the style sheet file as the question shows.